# numpy shows wrong dimension for list of images

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy array of following shape `(196276,16)` where there are 16 numpy array images of shape `(50,50)` . I want the input shape to be `(196276,16,50,50,1)`.

[image]

I have searched for a solution where we can create `zeroes` array using `np.zeroes([y.shape[0],16,50,50,1])` and then do copy but these seems quite slow. Can it be done more elegantly?

Comment: What's the `dtype` of this array?  What's the significance of the `196276` dimension?

Comment: I have `196276`  utterances of `16` images so `196276x16` such images of shape `50x50`. `dtype` for `x` is `object` and that of `x[0][0]` is `uint8` .

Comment: So you have 2d array that contains images, arrays themselves.  This isn't a 4 or 5d array.  Most likely one or more of the images differ in `shape`.  The construction method could have also intentionally created an object array.  In any case, `reshape` isn't work.  You need to check the shape of all those elements.

Comment: every images are of `50x50` with `uint8` dtype. my doubt is whether I can bring this dimension noticed in `x` . which currently isn't happening.

Comment: I suppose you could try `np.stack(x.ravel())`.  If it works, you can proceed with the reshape.  If the shapes do differ, it will raise an error.

Comment: Thanks, I see some images out of `3140416` are not of shape `50x50` instead of `41x50` or `45x50`. I'll see what can be done.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj now the reshape works, I discarded wrong dimension images.